# Custom view created with Xib not working in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I've created a custom view with the help of an `.Xib` file. When I create the view programmatically and add it to my ViewController it works just fine. But if I create a UIView in Interface Builder and set the class to my `CustomView` class and run it, it doesn't show up.

This is the Code in my `CustomView` class:

```
@IBOutlet var view: UIView!

init() {
    super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    setup()
}


func setup() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 10.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 52.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}


func presentInView(superView:UIView) {

    superView.addSubview(view)

    // Define Constraints
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 90.0)
    view.addConstraint(height)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    superView.addConstraints([topConstraint,leftConstraint, rightConstraint])
}
```

In the `.Xib` file I set the class for the `Files Owner` to `CustomView` and the connect the IBOutlet `view` to the main view in the `.Xib`.

In my ViewController I did this to add the `CustomView` to it:

```
let customView = CustomView()
customView.presentInView(superView: self.view)
```

When I add a `UIView` in Interface Builder it should work just as it does when I do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the size of the `view`, the `IBOutlet` that I connected to my view in the `.Xib` file. When I created my `CustomView` in code, I also called the `presentInView` method, which I thought was unnecessary when created in the Interface Builder because I set the constraints there. But I forgot, that the constraints that I set in Interface Builder are for the class itself and not for its `view` outlet. So the `view` needs constraints to hold it in its superview, which is not the `ViewController.view` but `CustomView`. Thats why I also have to write `self.addSubview(view)`

With these changes it works. Here is the final code:

```
func setup() {

    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 10.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 52.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addSubview(view)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.addConstraints([topConstraint,leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint])

}
```

The `presentInView` method is no longer needed.

Hope it helps if someone else has a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you assign CustomView Class to you uiview in interface Builder.

[image: Assigning UIView As you CustomView]

Comment: Yes I did assign it just as you did

Comment: did you set NSLayoutConstraint From interface builder and make them outlet  for  further change

Comment: Yes I created constraints but I didn't make it an outlet because I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Right but i can see NSLayout Constraints in you code as well  can you  take image of you interface build including constraint preview

Comment: if you set you customview class in interface then why its showing outlet  like this

Comment: @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

Comment: it should be  like  this @IBOutlet var view: CustomView!

Comment: Yes but the NSLayoutConstraints are only defined and added to my custom view, when `presentInView` gets called. And this only happens if I call it manually when I created the `CustomView`programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128179/discussion-between-aftab-muhammed-khan-and-codey).

Comment: The `view` Outlet is connected to the main view in my `.Xib` file, this is how I reference to to view in the `.Xib` file. It should not be set to my `CustomView` class.